# Why can't some people view my images?

Tags: support, images

Sometimes I get comments that people can't view my images, even though I can view them perfectly on the posts on different computers. Are you guys able to view the images of my question here:?

[Have they solved this exercise correct?(banach space, function space).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813407/have-they-solved-this-excercise-correctbanach-space-function-space)?

Here are the pictures I posed in the post:

http://s27.postimg.org/y8d4c57wz/image.png

http://s1.postimg.org/am6ii8anz/image.png

Comment: In the post you link to the user in [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813407/have-they-solved-this-excercise-correctbanach-space-function-space#comment1680988_813407) did not say that they cannot *view* the images, but that typed text is easier to *read* than text posted as images.

Comment: I understand, I've gotten the same comments in these two posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800994/monotone-class-theorem-proof  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695673/asymptotic-normal-behaviour-of-the-mle-question-about-proof, are you able to see the pictures clearly?

Comment: BTW if you want to include images in you posts, preferred way seems to be using the SE editor interface, in order to avoid link rot. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205/permanent-picture-uploads/4212#4212).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I will try to have that in mind next time I post an image.

Comment: I can only see the thumbnails of your image. For example, the image in the question "monotone class theorem, proof" is a 167 x 180 jpeg. It is way too small to has any use.

Comment: @achillehui For me it is 643*690, it is weird that it is different for different users. Maybe it is something with the hosting site, I don't know.

Comment: I have reuploaded the two full sized images in the two questions mentioned in comment to MSE's imgur account and modified your question to point to them. In the future, if you want to post images, please upload to MSE's imgur account. postimg.org seems to have a pretty bad reputation in terms of malicious content.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you very much for your help. I have one more question. I know how to upload to imgur, I tried it and I do not need an account, but how do I upload to the MSE account?

Comment: Above the edit box for your question/answer, there is a little icon that looks like a picture. You can use it to add a picture from your computer, it will upload the image to SE's imgur's account automatically.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you!